# Ajax/PHP form getting serialized select value

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

Right now the form sends the correct info but is missing the state. I am using an Ajax success function. The only thing is that the value is not fixed one but depends on which state is picked. How could I go about it?

JS:

```
$('#sendFormBtn').live('click', function(){
        formdata = $('#submitForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', 
                url: 'includes/contactForm.php',
                data: formdata, 
                success: function(){
                    $('input[name=name]').val('Name');
                    $('input[name=email]').val('Email');
                    $('input[name=address]').val('Address');
                    $('input[name=state]').val('');
                    $('input[name=city]').val('City');
                    $('input[name=zip]').val('Zip Code');
                    $('textarea[name=message]').val('Leave a message');
                }
        });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="submitForm">
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <td width="223">
                <input type="text" size="35" name="fullname" value="Full Name" onFocus="if(this.value == 'Full Name') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Full Name';}" />
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="35" name="youremail" value="Your Email" onFocus="if(this.value == 'Your Email') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your Email';}" />
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="35" name="address" value="Address" onFocus="if(this.value == 'Address') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Address';}" />
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="35" name="city" value="City" onFocus="if(this.value == 'City') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'City';}" />
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <p style="float:left; color:#FFF; padding-right:5px;">State/Zip</p>
                <select name="states">
                    <option value="alabama">AL</option>
                    <option value="alaska">AK</option>
                    <option value="arizona">AZ</option>
                    <option value="georgia">GA</option>
                    <option value="kentucky">KY</option>
                    <option value="louisiana">LA</option>
                    <option value="nebraska">NE</option>
                    <option value="nevada">NV</option>
                    <option value="new hampshire">NH</option>
                    <option value="new jersey">NJ</option>
                    <option value="new york">NY</option>
                    <option value="north carolina">NC</option>
                    <option value="washington">WA</option>
                    <option value="west verginia">WV</option>
                </select>

                <input type="text" size="8" maxlength="7" name="zip" value="Zip Code" onFocus="if(this.value == 'Zip Code') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Zip Code';}" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea cols="28" rows="6" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Leave a message'" onfocus="if(this.value =='Leave a message' ) this.value=''">Leave a message</textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td height="16">
                <input type="submit" name="submit_order" id="sendFormBtn" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You want to get back select named "state" value in 'includes/contactForm.php' ?

Comment: What depends on which state is picked??

Comment: @JBRTRND-DEV yes, that is right.

Comment: So you mean that the select element of your form isn't serialized ? Are you sure that a value is set ?

Comment: @dm03514 the state that gets picked, i would like to back select name "state" value in 'includes/contactForm.php'

Comment: @JBRTRND-DEV the select element has a name of "states". I am confused about the value since it is an options pick list. The main purpose is for the user to select the state and along with all the other information send it to the 'includes/contactForm.php'

Comment: have you logged the formdata?? what is it giving you? is it an empty string is it non existant?? `console.log($('#submitForm').serialize();`

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using the wrong key to access the value of your `<select name="states">`. In your PHP, you should be looking at **`$_POST['states']`**, not `$_POST['state']`.

**Note:** `<select name="states">` is not an `<input>`, so if you want to do something to it with jQuery, you can get at it with **`$('select[name=states]')`**, not `$('input[name=state]')`